# Datetime Javascript to Datetime C#

Tags: javascript, post, datetime

Estoy tratando de enviar un objeto por medio de una petición POST, sin embargo tengo algunos problemas con uno de los atributos de dicho objeto (datetime).

```
date = $("#dpkparam").val();             
fecha = new Date(date.replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"));

var perfil = {};
    perfil.idperfil = 100;
    perfil.nombre = "nuevoperfil";
    perfil.LogFechacrea = fecha;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: pathservicehost + '/perfiles',
        data: JSON.stringify(perfil),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data, textStatus, res) {
            alert("Perfil Ok...");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert('Perfil Falló... ');
        }
    });
```

La clase que intento guardar en la base de datos es la siguiente:

```
public class CPerfil : CGenerico<int>
{
    [DataMember]
    public int idperfil;

    [DataMember]
    public string nombre;

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime LogFechacrea;

}

public void save(CPerfil obj)
{
    using (SEntidades.Entidades ctx = new SEntidades.Entidades())
    {
        perfil objPerfil = new perfil();
        objPerfil.idperfil = obj.idperfil;
        objPerfil.descripcion = obj.nombre;
        objPerfil.log_fechacrea = DateTime.Now;
        //objPerfil.log_fechacrea = obj.LogFechacrea;  error

        ctx.perfil.AddObject(objPerfil);
        ctx.SaveChanges();

        return 1;
    }
}
```

El error se encuentra en la fecha ... y lo que necesito saber es cual es la manera de enviar dicho atributo.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que error tienes?, ¿podrias mostrar tu controller?

Comment: Cuando envio el json junto con el atributo fecha (y el valor obviamente) el servicio no se consume, sin embargo si no lo tomo en cuenta todo se ejecuta normalmente.

Comment: Si haces un debug, que valor tienes esto `obj.LogFechacrea;`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta ... el problema es que no se llega a consumir el servicio ... el error que obtengo es 400 (Bad Request) .. es por eso que lo que creo esta lanzando dicho error es el formato de la fecha que no coincide con el de la clase CPerfil. Saludos

Comment: Ahhh Ok, Utilizas WebInvoke para recibir los valores?

Comment: Sospecho que JSON no puede serializar la fecha tal vez no reconozca el formato, haz una prueba y en el campo de fecha manda una cadena por ejemplo '2016/4/14' o '2016-4-14'

Comment: @ATM gracias por tu respuesta ... lo intentaré.

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar el metodo format() de moment.js

Comment: Tambien es importante [leer esto (esta en ingles):](http://thewebjedi.com/be/post/2014/02/22/dates-and-time-zones-in-javascript-c-and-sql-server.aspx)

Comment: @ATM el problema esta en el atributo **LogFechacrea** de la clase **CPerfil** me imagino que como tu dices el JSON que envio no puede ser serializado por el tipo de dicho atributo, cambie el tipo a **string** y efectivamente después de una transformación de string a datetime todo funciono perfectamente. Lo que me gustaria saber es si es posible enviar un objeto DateTime dentro de un objeto JSON o no. Gracias.

Comment: Claro que es posible

Comment: No cambies el tipo de dato en el servidor, el problema creo que esta en  `fecha = new Date(date.replace(/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3")); ` Que valor estas obteniendo aqui?

Comment: Que valor obtienes en date? y que valor obtienes en fecha?

Comment: El valor en date es: **14/04/2016**, dicho valor lo parseo a formato DateTime y lo que obtengo es algo como esto (variable fecha): **Thu Apr 14 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Hora est. Pacifico, Sudamerica)** .

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();        
var month = date.getMonth();    
var year = date.getFullYear();  
var hour = date.getHours();     
var minute = date.getMinutes(); 
var second = date.getSeconds(); 


var time = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ':' + minute + ':' + second;

DateTime.ParseExact(YourString, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Siempre es bueno agregar un pequeño texto explicando el codigo de una respuesta :)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza la libreria [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) para formatear tu fecha, JSON puede serializarla en el cliente y deserializarla en el servidor

```
date = $("#dpkparam").val();             
fecha = moment(date).format();

var perfil = {};
perfil.idperfil = 100;
perfil.nombre = "nuevoperfil";
perfil.LogFechacrea = fecha;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: pathservicehost + '/perfiles',
    data: JSON.stringify(perfil),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data, textStatus, res) {
        alert("Perfil Ok...");
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert('Perfil Falló... ');
    }
});
```

Explicación:

moment(date).format() convierte el formato de la fecha a ISO-8601 conservando la informacion de UTC

**En el post del servidor:**

La fecha recibida tiene la propiedad DateTimeKind = Local.

Para guardar la fecha en el servidor de base de datos tienes que cambiar la propiedad DateTimeKind a DateTimeKind.Utc

```
objPerfil.log_fechacrea=  objPerfil.log_fechacrea.ToUniversalTime();
```

**En el GET del servidor**

Antes de enviar la fecha del servidor al cliente tienes que asegurarte que la  propiedad DateTimeKind sea Utc

```
objPerfil.log_fechacrea=  DateTime.SpecifyKind(objPerfil.log_fechacrea, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

**En el cliente**

De esta manera JSON entiende que debe aplicar el offset especificado en el formato UTC y mostrar la hora local.

[Esto me ayudo mucho](http://thewebjedi.com/be/post/2014/02/22/dates-and-time-zones-in-javascript-c-and-sql-server.aspx)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta ... intentare tu solución. Saludos.